# Having trouble with creating a JFrame and adding text to it

Tags: java, jframe

I've been trying to setup a JFrame with text but I'm having trouble.  I can create the JFrame, but I can't get a background color or text to work with it.

```
import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

class FundManager {

    JFrame window;
    JPanel panel;
    JLabel text;

    public void createWindow()
    {

        //Create the window
        window = new JFrame();
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.setSize(960, 540);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        //Create the panel
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.RED);

        //Create the label
        text = new JLabel("test");

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        FundManager.createWindow();

    }

}
```

My `createWindow()` method is not running and I get the error:

> cannot make a static reference to to the non-static method.

However, when I make it static the whole program breaks.

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that you need an instance of FundManager before you can call the method createWindow(). Try the code below instead.

```
new FundManager().createWindow();
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you cannot make a call to FundManager.createWindow(), because createWindow() is not a static method. You need an instance of FundManager.

Furthermore, you are not adding the panel nor the text field to the frame. You are only declaring them. This is a quick example of how you could locate the elements inside the frame:

```
JFrame window;
JPanel panel;
JLabel text;

public void createWindow() {

    // Create the window
    window = new JFrame();
    window.setVisible(true);
    window.setSize(960, 540);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    // Create the panel
    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
    panel.setBackground(Color.RED);

    // Create the label
    text = new JLabel("test");
    text.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 30));
    text.setLocation(100, 100);
    panel.add(text);

    window.getContentPane().add(panel);
    window.pack();

}
```

And run this with:

```
new FundManager().createWindow();
```